# Go channel didn't work for producer/consumer sample

Tags: go

I've just installed Go on Mac, and here's the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Product(ch chan<- int) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Product:", i)
        ch <- i
    }
}

func Consumer(ch <-chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        a := <-ch
        fmt.Println("Consmuer:", a)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go Product(ch)
    go Consumer(ch)
    time.Sleep(500)
}
```

I "go run producer_consumer.go", there's no output on screen, and then it quits.

Any problem with my program ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Your example is not going to complete in the 500 nanoseconds before main exits.

Comment: Thanks, time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather verbose answer, but to put it simply:

- Using `time.Sleep` to wait until *hopefully* other routines have completed their jobs is bad.
- The consumer and producer shouldn't know anything about each other, apart from the type they exchange over the channel. Your code relies on both consumer and producer knowing how many ints will be passed around. Not a realistic scenario
- Channels can be iterated over (think of them as a thread-safe, shared slice)
- channels should be closed

At the bottom of this rather verbose answer where I attempt to explain some basic concepts and best practices (well, better practices), you'll find your code rewritten to work *and* display all the values *without* relying on `time.Sleep`. I've not tested that code, but should be fine

---

Right, there's a couple of problems here. Just as a bullet-list:

1. Your channel is buffered to 1, which is fine, but it's not necessary
2. Your channel is never closed
3. You're waiting 500ns, then exit regardless of the routines having completed, or even started processing for that matter.
4. There's no centralised control on over the routines, once you've started them, you have 0 control. If you hit ctrl+c, you might want to cancel routines when writing code that'll handle important data. Check signal handling, and context for this

## Channel buffer

Seeing as you already know how many values you're going to push onto your channel, why not simply create `ch := make(chan int, 100)`? That way your publisher can continue to push messages onto the channel, regardless of what the consumer does.

You don't *need* to do this, but adding a sensible buffer to your channel, depending on what you're trying to do, is definitely worth checking out. At the moment, though, both routines are using `fmt.Println` & co, which is going to be a bottleneck either way. Printing to STDOUT is thread-safe, and buffered. This means that each call to `fmt.Print*` is going to acquire a lock, to avoid text from both routines to be combined.

## Closing the channel

You could simply push all the values onto your channel, and then close it. This is, however, bad form. The rule of thumb WRT channels is that channels are created and closed in the same routine. Meaning: you're creating the channel in the main routine, that's where it should be closed.

You need a mechanism to sync up, or at least keep tabs on whether or not your routines have completed their job. That's done using the `sync` package, or through a second channel.

```
// using a done channel
func produce(ch chan<- int) <-chan struct{} {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        // all values have been published
        // close done channel
        close(done)
    }()
    return done
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    done := produce(ch)
    go consume(ch)
    <-done // if producer has done its thing
    close(ch) // we can close the channel
}

func consume(ch <-chan int) {
    // we can now simply loop over the channel until it's closed
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Consumed %d\n", i)
    }
}
```

OK, but here you'll still need to wait for the `consume` routine to complete.

You may have already noticed that the `done` channel technically isn't closed in the same routine that creates it either. Because the routine is defined as a closure, however, this is an acceptable compromise. Now let's see how we could use a waitgroup:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func product(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done() // signal we've done our job
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1) // I'm adding a routine to the channel
    go produce(&wg, ch)
    wg.Wait() // will return once `produce` has finished
    close(ch)
}
```

OK, so this looks promising, I can have the routines tell me when they've finished their tasks. But if I add both consumer and producer to the waitgroup, I can't simply iterate over the channel. The channel will only ever get closed if both routines invoke `wg.Done()`, but if the consumer is stuck looping over a channel that'll never get closed, then I've created a deadlock.

## Solution:

A hybrid would be the easiest solution at this point: Add the consumer to a waitgroup, and use the done channel in the producer to get:

```
func produce(ch chan<- int) <-chan struct{} {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(done)
    }()
    return done
}

func consume(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch <-chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Consumer: %d\n", i)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    done := produce(ch)
    wg.Add(1)
    go consume(&wg, ch)
    <- done // produce done
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    // consumer done
    fmt.Println("All done, exit")
}
```

Comment: "The rule of thumb WRT channels is that channels are created and closed in the same routine. Meaning: you're creating the channel in the main routine, that's where it should be closed." Disagree in this case. If there's only one sender, channels should be closed by that sender, which isn't necessarily the creator. The introduction of the done channel offers no benefit but increases complexity.

Comment: @Peter: It's a rule of thumb, but a bit further down, I close a channel in a different routine, and actually state that it's acceptable in that case. It's not a hard-set rule, but when you create channels in the `main` routine, it's far more risky IMO. then closing a channel you create in a closure-routine

Answer (score 1):

As JimB hinted at, `time.Sleep` takes a `time.Duration`, not an integer. The [godoc](https://godoc.org/time#Sleep) shows an example of how to call this correctly. In your case, you probably want:

```
time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
```

The reason that your program is exiting quickly (but not giving you an error) is due to the (somewhat surprising) way that `time.Duration` is implemented.

`time.Duration` is simply a type alias for `int64`. Internally, it uses the value to represent the duration in nanoseconds. When you call `time.Sleep(500)`, the compiler will gladly interpret the numeric literal `500` as a `time.Duration`. Unfortunately, *that means 500 ns*.

`time.Millisecond` is a constant equal to the number of nanoseconds in a millisecond (1,000,000). The nice thing is that requiring you to do that multiplication explicitly makes it obvious to that caller what the units are on that argument. Unfortunately, `time.Sleep(500)` is perfectly valid go code but doesn't do what most beginners would expect.

Comment: Still not good enough, in real life, your consumer usually doesn't know how many  values to read from a channel, and both routines write to stdout, which is a bottleneck. Upping the number of values from 100 to a higher number will result in you eventually needing to change the duration of the sleep time, again changing it depending on the machine you're running on. You'll probably end up sleeping too long on some machines, which is just a waste

Comment: Oh absolutely, waiting an arbitrary amount of time is definitely not the right way to handle this in general. I figured OP would want to understand why their program behaved in the way it did, though, especially because this is a common trap for beginners.

Comment: There's nothing surprising about not seeing an error when you write `time.Sleep(1000)` BTW. the `1000` is an untyped constant. The expression in which you use this value will determine the type. It's well documented behaviour.

Comment: You and I might not get surprised by this behavior, but beginners clearly do as evidenced by the _question we are answering_.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed slightly(expanded time.Sleep) your code. Works fine on my Linux x86_64

```
func Product(ch chan<- int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Product:", i)
        ch <- i
    }
}
func Consumer(ch <-chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        a := <-ch
        fmt.Println("Consmuer:", a)
    }
}
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go Product(ch)
    go Consumer(ch)
    time.Sleep(10000)
}
```

Output
go run s1.go

```
Product: 0
Product: 1
Product: 2
```